# Laravel Eloquent sum relation's column through other relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

Let's say I have these modules:

- Coupon
- Order (.., coupon_id)
- Item (..., order_id, price)

And there are those relations:

- `Coupon` **Has Many** `Order`.
- `Order` **Has Many** `Item`.

So far so good.

Now I want to sum the price of the items that belongs to the orders that belongs to the coupon. So I thought about doing something like this:

```
Coupon::orders->items->sum('price');
```

Well, it won't work because `orders()` method returns a `Collection` of the relation:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

I'm getting an error that says `item` property is protected. I found out that it doesn't related to my `Item` module, it's just because `Collection` has `protected $items = [];`.

So, after I cleared out some facts, my question/problem is, How can I sum the `items->price` of the `orders` that belong to `Coupon`?

---

Of course I can achieve my goal by doing a foreach loop like this:

```
$price = 0;

foreach (Coupon:orders as $order)
    $price += $order->items->sum('price');

return $price;
```

But I'm looking for a cleaner solution. Anyone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few ways to achieve that:

```
$coupon_id; // the one you're looking for

Item::whereHas('order', function ($q) use ($coupon_id) {
  $q->where('coupon_id', $coupon_id);
})->sum('items.price');

// OR

// Coupon model
public function items()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough(Item::class, Order::class);
}

Coupon::find($coupon_id)->items()->sum('price') // aggregate query
Coupon::find($coupon_id)->items->sum('price') // sum on collection

// OR
Coupon::with('orders.items')->find($coupon_id)->orders->pluck('items')->collapse()->sum('price');
```

Comment: Thank you, I've used the third option.